# Eclipse: showing breakpoints in separate column possible?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

Per default, Eclipse shows breakpoints in a column on the very left of a code line, together with occurrence indicators (arrows) and tag markers (clipboards). Both of these are overlapping breakpoints if they occur on the same line.

Is it possible to show preakpoints in a separate column instead? I am using the source window in the Java and Debug perspective, just in case that it looks different in other perspectives.

As you can see here, any breakpoints on the left side are obscured
[image]

Comment: makrom that's interesting, never wondered about it/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope, that cant be done -- at least up to eclipse neo. maybe u formulate a feature request or write that code urself?

**workaround**

breakpoints and occurrence markers are both *annotations*. 
Annotations can be configured with regard on how and where they are displayed in preferences: `general/editors/text editors/annotations`

since i had the same problem, ages back, i turned off **vertical ruler** for the ones that get most in the way, e.g. **occurrences** and **search results**.

Comment: Great, thanks for your reply. Just turning occurrence markers off is good enough for me, these arrows are overkill anyway (on top of the markers in the overview bar on the right as well marked occurrences in the text window).